# How to strip off certain hexadecimal characters in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal, special-characters

I have gathered a wordlist for person to follow on twitter. However, there is a problem.
When i cat and do xxd a extra hidden characters are found. i.e 1b5b 6d1b 5b4b . I need to strip those character. Lets say 007_sharky is name , when i cat it i get
`00000000: 3030 375f 7368 6172 6b79 1b5b 6d1b 5b4b  007_sharky.[m.[K 00000010: 0a`

But i need to get

`00000000: 3030 375f 7368 6172 6b79 0a              007_sharky.`

Its not for only one line for multiple line, so i can do

```bsh
cat file | while read line; do
something 
done
```

I m missing the something part, how can i remove those character.
Also i deleted the file mistakely again after formatting using cut awk and grep again i got this. Also the first pic is new one and second pic is old one. [image: done][image: Bash xxd image]

https://gist.github.com/machinexa2/293823309ad804866b32b59eda17526d

Comment: Similar: [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684)

Comment: Ok didnt knew. Anyways thanks

Comment: But i didnt understand what are they doing anyways hmm lot of sed scripts

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Also, could you please [edit] your question and show us the output of `head -n1  Twitter.Account | od -c`? That might show the extra characters in a way that's easier for some of us to parse.

Comment: @terdon done done

Comment: Also, i will use code blocks next time @terdon

Comment: @DipeshSunrait please use them *this* time.

Comment: I suppose you could use `sed` to do something about the escapes but I can't see from the images what the data actually is.

Comment: @muru https://gist.github.com/machinexa2/293823309ad804866b32b59eda17526d

Comment: @ikkachu https://gist.github.com/machinexa2/293823309ad804866b32b59eda17526d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are exactly 6 extra bytes at the beginning of each line. So you can use this:

```
cut -b 7- temp > result
```